# Intersecting cubic equations and roots.

Tags: polynomials, cubics

I know that it is possible to find all roots of a cubic using the cubic formula. Now when I have a cubic $P(x)$, I create the simultaneous equations:

$$P(x)=y \quad\text{and}\quad P(y)=x$$

I want to find all the roots using just algebraic manipulation and cubic formula.

---

My previous work: I know at most $3$ roots lie on $x=y$, and therefore I will set $P(x)=x$ and that is a cubic, which I can solve.

But I don't know how to get the remaining $6$ roots within the constraints of the problem. Can someone help me?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I know how to find cubic roots, so I need to solve the equation system using only cubic roots and algebraic manipulation/

Comment: @dxiv For a general quadratic the Galois group remains $C_2$ (starting from $x^2 + bx + c$ the new discriminant is $(b - 1)^2 - 4(c + 1)$).

Comment: @WEIMINGCHEN You did not explain the motivation behind the question. For all practical purposes, the answer would be to solve it numerically. Any algebraic solution, even if it turns out that one exists (which hasn't been established yet), would be very painfully complicated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[tl;dr]` $\;$ The resulting sextic is solvable, but the calculations are extremely laborious, so for all practical purposes the answer would be to solve it numerically.

Let the general depressed cubic be $P(x) = x^3 + a x + b$ then the period-$2$ [periodic points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_point) of $P$ other than the [fixed points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_(mathematics)) are the roots of the [sextic](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28%28x%5E3%2Bax%2Bb%29%5E3%2Ba%28x%5E3%2Bax%2Bb%29%2Bb-x%29%2F%28x%5E3%2Bax%2Bb-x%29):

$$
\frac{P\left(P(x)\right) - x}{P(x) - x} = x^6 + (2 a + 1) x^4 + 2 b x^3 + (a^2 + a + 1) x^2 + (2 a + 1) b x + a + b^2 + 1
$$

The [Tschirnhaus transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tschirnhaus_transformation) $\,z = x^3 + (a - 1) x + b\,$ [reduces](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=collect%5B+resultant%28x%5E6+%2B+%282+a+%2B+1%29+x%5E4+%2B+2+b+x%5E3+%2B+%28a%5E2+%2B+a+%2B+1%29+x%5E2+%2B+%282+a+%2B+1%29+b+x+%2B+a+%2B+b%5E2+%2B+1%2C+z+-+x%5E3+-+%28a+-+1%29+x+-+b%2C+x%29%2C+z%5D) it to the cubic in $t = z^2\,$:

$$
t^3 + 6 a \,t^2 + 3 (3 a^2 - 4 a - 4) \,t + 4 a^3 - 12 a^2 + 27 b^2 + 16
$$

It follows that the original sextic is solvable.

It would be technically possible to solve the latter cubic, then for each of the three $t$ roots calculate the corresponding $z = \pm t^{1/2}$ and solve each of the six Tschirnhaus cubics. That would give $18$ potential $x$ roots for the original sextic, out of which the $6$ actual roots would need to be identified and retained. Or, once established that the sextic is in fact solvable, follow the reference quoted on wikipedia's page on [sextics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sextic_equation) *T. R. Hagedorn, General formulas for solving solvable sextic equations, J. Algebra 233 (2000), 704-757*, to the tune of 54 loaded pages. Either way, the exact calculations are *very* heavy, so numerical root-finding would be preferred in practical applications.

---

[ *EDIT* ] $\;$ Finding the Tschirnhaus transformation was essentially trial and error. I thought I'd look for a bicubic (if that's what a cubic in $z^2$ can be called) and started with a depressed cubic substitution $z = x^3 + u x + v$. Canceling the $x^5$ term gave $v = b$ and canceling the $x^3$ term required $u \in \{a-1, a+1/2, a+2\}$. Out of the three choices, $u=a-1$ turned out to cancel the linear term as well.

---

[ *EDIT #2* ] $\;$ Another Tschirnhaus transformation that settles the question of solvability even more directly is $z = x^3 + (a+1)x +b$, which [reduces](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=resultant%28x%5E6%2B%282+a%2B1%29x%5E4%2B2b+x%5E3%2B%28a%5E2%2Ba%2B1%29x%5E2%2B%282a%2B1%29b+x%2Ba%2Bb%5E2%2B1%2Cz-x%5E3-a+x-b-x%29+-+%28z%5E3%2B%28a%2B2%29z-b%29%5E2) the sextic to (the square of) a cubic:

$$
z^3+(a+2)z-b
$$

In light of the related question [Irreducibility and Galois group of the 2
-periodic points of a (cubic) polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4664288/irreducibility-and-galois-group-of-the-2-periodic-points-of-a-cubic-polynomi) it may be worth noting that something similar holds true for the reduced quartic $P(x)=x^4+ax+b$. In that case $\frac{P\left(P(x)\right)-x}{P(x)-x}$ has degree $12$, and the substitution $z=P(x)+x$ [reduces](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=resultant%28%28%28x%5E4%2Ba+x%2Bb%29%5E4%2Ba%28x%5E4%2Ba+x%2Bb%29%2Bb-x%29%2F%28x%5E4%2Ba+x%2Bb-x%29%2Cz-x%5E4-ax-b-x%2Cx%29) it to (the square of) a sextic.

Comment: [+1} Very very interesting.

Comment: A [particular case](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2117378/305862) found using [approach0](https://approach0.xyz/) once more. Interesting elements also in the answers to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2680131/305862) but for the quadratic case.

Comment: As for lower bounds, I think $x \mapsto P(x)$ is an order $2$ element of $G$.

Comment: More empirics: let's call the combined polynomial $Q$. Then $Q$ is irreducible iff $R(x) = x^3 + (a + 2)x + b$ is. Let $G = \operatorname{Gal}(Q)$ and $H = \operatorname{Gal}(R)$. Then $G$ is one of: $C_2 \times S_4$, $C_2 \times A_4$, $S_4$ and $D_6 = C_2 \times S_3$. I am using the group name database notation, so $D_6$ has $12$ elements. If $G = C_2 \times S_4$ then $H = S_3$. When $G$ is smaller I see no correlation, except if $a = -1$ then $G \cong D_6$ and $H = A_3$.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you, and thanks for the pointers. The general cubic case looks to be a lot more challenging, though. A constructive answer could be to find a clever (or lucky ;-)) Tschirnhaus transformation of degree $\le 4$ to bring it down to a cubic or a quadratic in powers of the auxiliary variable, or an otherwise reducible sextic. But that's neither trivial to search, nor guaranteed to find.

Comment: @ronno Thank you, interesting findings. Don't think it helps here, but speaking of discriminants which you mentioned in a previous comment, the original cubic has $\Delta_P=-(4a^3+27b^2)$ while the associated sextic [has](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=discriminant%5Bx%5E6+%2B+%282+a+%2B+1%29+x%5E4+%2B+2+b+x%5E3+%2B+%28a%5E2+%2B+a+%2B+1%29+x%5E2+%2B+%282+a+%2B+1%29+b+x+%2B+a+%2B+b%5E2+%2B+1%2C+x%5D) $\Delta_Q=-\left(4(a+1)(a-2)^2+27 b^2\right) \left(4(a+2)^3+27b^2\right)^2$. FWIW an alternative way to write it is $Q(x) = P^2(x)+x P(x)+x^2+P'(0)+1$ though that doesn't look useful, either.

Comment: @JeanMarie May be just luck, but I have that nagging feeling there is more reason to it why the transformation worked.

Comment: Great update! Could you add how you found the Tschirnhaus transformation?

Comment: @ronno Thanks. Edited that in at the end of the answer. Wish I had some deep insight why that worked, but I can't claim that.

Comment: I've asked a follow-up question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4664288/irreducibility-and-galois-group-of-the-2-periodic-points-of-a-cubic-polynomi). Also thought I should note explicitly that your Tschirnhaus transformation is $P(x) - x$ though I still don't know why it works without just computation.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer : this is not an answer, therefore not to be upvoted (neither downvoted...) : just a (Geogebra) figure to clarify the question :

[image]

Here we have only 5 intersections. In some other cases there will be only $3$ for example...

Comment: Sometimes just one, but always at least one.

Comment: please can someone give solution???