# Irreducibility and Galois group of the $2$-periodic points of a (cubic) polynomial

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials

This question arose in observations made while trying to answer [Intersecting cubic equations and roots.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4663164/intersecting-cubic-equations-and-roots/4663267). Consider a (depressed) cubic polynomial $P(x) = x^3 + ax + b$, either over $\mathbb{Q}$ with $a, b \in \mathbb{Q}$, or over $\mathbb{Q}(a, b)$ (or over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}(a, b)$ or $\mathbb{C}(a, b)$ if that's easier). Then the set $\{ c \mid P(P(c)) = c, P(c) \ne c \}$ is given by the roots of the *polynomial* $$Q(x) = \frac{P(P(x)) - x}{P(x) - x} = x^6 + (2 a + 1) x^4 + 2 b x^3 + (a^2 + a + 1) x^2 + (2 a + 1) b x + a + b^2 + 1$$

@dxiv's answer to that question shows that $Q$ becomes a cubic in $z^2$ under the Tschirnhaus transformation $z = P(x) - x$, in particular its Galois group is always solvable. For $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $|a|, |b| \le 100$ the following observations hold:

- If $Q$ is irreducible then so is $R(x) = x^3 + (a+2)x + b$ (*a previous version of the question incorrectly also claimed the converse*). @dxiv's comment notes that the Tschirnhaus transformation $z = P(x) + x$ converts $Q(x)$ to $R(-z)^2$, which seems relvant.
- Let $G = \operatorname{Gal}(Q)$ and $H = \operatorname{Gal}(R)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ when $Q$ is irreducible. Then $G$ is one of: $C_2 \times S_4$, $C_2 \times A_4$, $S_4$ and $D_6 = C_2 \times S_3$, with orders $48$, $24$, $24$ and $12$ respectively.
- If $G = C_2 \times S_4$ then $H = S_3$.

[Apparently](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/%7Ematyd/GroupNames/T15.html#6t11) $C_2 \times S_4$ is the unique transitive subgroup of $S_6$ of order $48$, though I am not sure if it's unique up to conjugacy. From these observations, and my informal impression of Hilbert's irreducibility type arguments, I expect that the Galois group of $Q$ over $\mathbb{Q}(a, b)$ is $C_2 \times S_4$, and the smaller groups occur as further transitive subgroups.

My broad informal question is, what is going on? To ask a single precise question: **is the Galois group of $Q$ over $\mathbb{Q}(a, b)$ isomorphic to $C_2 \times S_4$?**

Related/follow-up questions that I might ask separately if not answered here:

- Can the irreducibility implication be inferred from the Tschirnhaus transformations? Is there an *a priori* reason to expect such a polynomial of degree smaller than $Q$ to exist?
- (How) does any of this generalize to $P$ of higher degrees and higher order periods (ie $P^n(c) = c$)? In particular, what construction yields $C_2 \times S_4$ (or whatever the correct Galois group is) from the parameters $(3, 2)$?

Comment: Another "nice" substitution is $z=P(x)+x$ which reduces the sextic to (the square of) a cubic. Even more interesting, the same substitution appears to also halve the degree  in the case of a quartic $P(x)$. I edited my answer to the linked question and included these observations, which might be of interest here, too.

Comment: @dxiv I think that is very relevant to the bolded question: $z^3 + (a + 2)z - b = - R(-z)$, so is irreducible iff $R$ is.

Comment: Guess I am missing something basic, but how does the *iff* follow in this case where the image of $Q(x)$ under the transformation is $R^{\color{red}{2}}(-z)\,$? Also, just out of curiosity, I wonder what clued you in to $R(z)$ before the second Tschirnhausen came into picture.

Comment: Oh I still don't know why it makes $Q$ irreducible. As for how I found $R$, I ran your sage code on $P$ and noticed that the output looked almost the same.

Comment: @Sil I've run a (I hope) corrected program and I believe the rest of the observations are correct. Thanks again for the corrections, and I apologize for changing the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $L$ be the splitting field of $Q(x)$ over $\mathbf{Q}(a,b)$. If $\alpha \in L$ is a root of $Q(x)$, then $P(\alpha)$ is also a root of $Q(x)$. Thus the roots of $Q(x)$ are divided up into three pairs:

$$\alpha, P(\alpha), \beta, P(\beta), \gamma, P(\gamma).$$

These are distinct because $Q(x)$ has non-zero discriminant and so is separable. Any automorphism sending $\alpha$ to $\sigma \alpha$ sends $P(\alpha)$ to $P(\sigma \alpha)$, and thus must preserve these three pairs. This puts a restriction on the Galois group $G = \mathrm{Gal}(L/\mathbf{Q}(a,b)) \subset S_6$, namely that it lies inside $\Gamma \subset S_6$, the maximal subgroup of $S_6$ preserving this decomposition.
We shall see that this group is $S_4 \times S_2$.

So far this all generalizes to roots of $P^{(n)}(x) = x$ with $P(x)$ general of degree $d$;
the roots of the corresponding polynomial $Q(x)$ will come in packets of $n$ roots which are iterates under $\alpha \rightarrow P(\alpha)$, and since $\sigma P(\alpha) = P(\sigma \alpha)$, the Galois group will commute with this automorphism, and thus give a restriction on the Galois group as lying inside the centralizer of this permutation.

Here are some more details in the case $(d,n) = (d,2)$. We have
$P^{(2)}(x) = x$ and $Q(x)$ has degree $d^2 - d$, the maximal group $\Gamma$ will preserve the $m:=(d^2-d)/2$ pairs. The largest such group naturally surjects to $S_m$ which describes how it acts on the $m$ pairs. The kernel consists of elements which just permute each pair which is the group $(\mathbf{Z}/2 \mathbf{Z})^m$. This is a group of order $2^m \cdot m!$ and is usually denoted

$$ S_2 \wr S_m =(S_2)^m \ltimes S_m.$$

The symbol on the LHS is the wreath product and this group is called $S_2$ *wreath* $S_m$; it is defined/identified with the semidirect product preserving $m$ pairs of elements described above.  If $\alpha$ is a root of $Q(x)$, the quotient $S_m$ corresponds to considering the Galois group of $\theta = \alpha + P(\alpha)$. You already noticed this when $m = 3$. If you take a random example with $d = 4$, say $P(x)=x^4+x+1$, you will find the Galois group of $Q(x)$ has order $2^6 \cdot 6! = 46080$, whereas if $d = 5$, say $P(x)=x^5+x+1$, it will have order $2^{10} 10! = 3715891200$. In neither case will it be solvable because the groups surject onto $S_6$ and $S_{10}$ respectively.

So far we have seen that $G$ is contained within this group $\Gamma$, but it is also equal to this group, since the group only gets smaller under specialization and one can compute at least one example with $a,b \in \mathbf{Q}$ for which this extension has Galois group $S_4 \times S_2$.

When $d=3$ and so $m=3$ something additional and  special happens, namely that there is an isomorphism

$$S_2 \wr S_3 \simeq S_2 \times S_4.$$

This is an exceptional isomorphism which has no analog for higher $d$.  You can see that $\Gamma \simeq S_4 \times S_2$ in a number of ways:

Label the pairs of roots which sum to zero as $(1,6)$, $(2,5)$, and $(3,4)$, the condition of being in $\Gamma$ is equivalent to commuting with $\sigma = (1,6)(2,5)(3,4)$. This is because

$$g \sigma g^{-1} = (g(1),g(6))(g(2),g(5))(g(3),g(4)).$$

So it suffices to show that the centralizer of $\sigma$ is $S_4 \times S_2$.

The order of the centralizer is the stabilizer of $G$ acting on $\sigma$ by conjugation. Since $\sigma$ has $15$ conjugates, the order of the stabilizer is $6!/15 = 48$ by the Orbit-Stabilizer theorem. Alternatively the previous description of $\Gamma$ shows that its order is $2^3 \cdot 3! = 48$.

**Claim:** The centralizer of $\sigma = (16)(25)(34) \in S_6$ is isomorphic to $S_4 \times S_2$.

**Proof One:** There is an outer automorphism of $S_6$ sending $\sigma$ to a $2$-cycle. The centralizer of $(1,2)$ certainly contains $S_2 \times S_4$ with the first $S_2$ generated by $(1,2)$ and the second $S_4$ acting on $3,4,5,6$. This has order $48$ so we are done.

As a remark, any $S_4 \times S_2$ inside $S_6$ has to normalize an element of order $2$. There are three conjugacy classes of order $2$ elements; $(**)$, $(**)(**)$, and $(**)(**)(**)$. The normalizer of the second conjugacy class has order $6!/45 = 16$, but the first two give the two conjugacy classes of $S_4 \times S_2 \subset S_6$, one that acts transitively and the other that doesn't, but which are interchanged by the exotic automorphism of $S_6$.

**Proof Two:** Let $C \subset \mathrm{SO}(3)$ denote the group of rotations that preserve the cube (the cube group), with faces labelled in the usual way. It's well known that $C \simeq S_4$ by the action on the $4$ diagonals of the cube. Now $C$ also acts faithfully on the faces, which realizes $S_4 = C$ as a subgroup of $S_6$. Moreover the image commutes with $\sigma$, because $C$ preserves the pairs of opposite faces of the cube. Finally, the reflection $-I \notin C$ both commutes with $C$ and maps to $\sigma$. The group $S_4 \times S_2 \simeq C \times \langle -I \rangle  \subset \mathrm{O}(3)$ acts faithfully on the six faces of the cube and also commutes with $\sigma$, and so its image in $S_6$ is isomorphic to $S_4 \times S_2$ and is the centralizer of $\sigma$.

Comment: Nicely done (+1). The first line also answers a question left open in my original answer, which I edited and addressed now.

Answer (score 1):

(*Following is partial work that may be useful, though it does not answer the actual questions*.)

In the case of the depressed cubic $\,P(x) = x^3 + ax + b\,$, the period-$2$ [periodic points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_point) of $P$ other than the [fixed points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_(mathematics)) are the roots of the [sextic](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28%28x%5E3%2Bax%2Bb%29%5E3%2Ba%28x%5E3%2Bax%2Bb%29%2Bb-x%29%2F%28x%5E3%2Bax%2Bb-x%29):

$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
Q(x) &= \frac{P(P(x)) - x \color{blue}{- P(x)} + \color{red}{P(x)}}{P(x) - x}
\\ &= \frac{P^3(x) + a P(x) + \cancel{b} - (\color{blue}{x^3 + a x + \cancel{b}}) }{P(x) - x} \color{red}{+ 1}
\\ &= P^2(x)+xP(x)+x^2+a+1 \tag{1}
\end{align}
$$

The [Tschirnhaus transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tschirnhaus_transformation) $z = P(x) + x = x^3 + (a+1)x +b$ [reduces](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=resultant%28x%5E6%2B%282+a%2B1%29x%5E4%2B2b+x%5E3%2B%28a%5E2%2Ba%2B1%29x%5E2%2B%282a%2B1%29b+x%2Ba%2Bb%5E2%2B1%2Cz-x%5E3-a+x-b-x%29+-+%28z%5E3%2B%28a%2B2%29z-b%29%5E2) the sextic to the square of a cubic $\,T^2(z)\,$ where $\,T(z) = -R(-z)\,$ in OP's notation:

$$
T(z) = z^3+(a+2)z-b \tag{2}
$$

It can be easily verified by hand (and [confirmed](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28%28P%2Bx%29%5E3%2B%28a%2B2%29%28P%2Bx%29-b%29%28P-x%29+-+%28P%2B2x%29%28P%5E3%2BaP%2Bb-x%29+where+P%3Dx%5E3%2Bax%2Bb) by WA) that:

$$
T(z) = T\left(P(x) + x\right) = \left(P(x) + 2x\right)Q(x) \tag{3}
$$

This verifies $\,Q(x)=0 \implies T(z)=0\,$, and it also indicates that $\,T(z)\,$ will have extraneous roots introduced by the factor $\,P(x)+2x\,$.

Unfortunately, this $\;$ <s>does not provide much insight into *why* this particular Tschirnhaus transformation results in a perfect square, effectively halving the degree of the equation in $\,z\,$ to solve. It also</s> $\small\color{lightgray}{\textit{(see EDIT at end about the crossed-out part)}}$ $\;$ does not answer the question about a possible relation between the irreducibility of $\,Q(x)\,$ and that of $\,T(z)\,$.

In the case of the general cubic $\,P(x) = x^3 + c x^2 + ax + b\,$ the same transformation $\,z = P(x) + x\,$ also results in the square of a cubic. The results similar to the above are (WA [1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=resultant%28%28P%5E3%2Bc+P%5E2%2Ba+P%2Bb-x%29%2F%28P-x%29%2Cz-%28P%2Bx%29%2Cx%29+where+P%3Dx%5E3%2Bc+x%5E2%2Ba+x%2Bb), [2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28%28P%2Bx%29%5E3+%2B+2+c+%28P%2Bx%29%5E2+%2B+%28c%5E2+%2B+a+%2B+2%29+%28P%2Bx%29+%2B+c+%2B+c+a+-+b%29+%28P+-+x%29+%2F+%28P%5E3+%2B+c+P%5E2+%2B+a+P+%2B+b+-+x%29+where+P%3Dx%5E3+%2B+c+x%5E2+%2B+a+x+%2B+b)):

$$
\begin{align}
Q(x) &= P^2(x) + x P(x) + x^2 + c \left(P(x) +  x\right) + a + 1 \tag{1'}
\\ T(z) &= z^3 + 2 c z^2 + (c^2 + a + 2) z + c + c a - b \tag{2'}
\\ &= \left(P(x) + 2 x + c\right) Q(x) \tag{3'}
\end{align}
$$

In the case of a reduced quartic $\,P(x) = x^4 + ax + b\,$ the transformation $\,z = P(x) + x\,$ results in the square of a sextic. The results similar to the above are (WA [1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=resultant%28%28P%5E4%2Ba+P%2Bb-x%29%2F%28P-x%29%2Cz-%28P%2Bx%29%2Cx%29+where+P%3Dx%5E4%2Ba+x%2Bb), [2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28%28P%2Bx%29%5E6+%2B+4+%28P%2Bx%29%5E3+-+4+b+%28P%2Bx%29%5E2+-+%28a+%2B+1%29%5E2%29+%28P+-+x%29+%2F+%28P%5E4+%2B+a+P+%2B+b+-+x%29+-+%28%28P+%2B+x%29%28%28P%2B2x%29%5E2+%2B+x%5E2%29+-+a+-+1%29+where+P%3Dx%5E4+%2B+a+x+%2B+b)):

$$
\begin{align}
Q(x) &= P^3(x) + x P^2(x) + x^2 P(x) + x^3 + a + 1 \tag{1''}
\\ T(z) &= z^6 + 4 z^3 - 4 b z^2 - (a + 1)^2 \tag{2''}
\\ &= \left(\left(P(x) + x\right)\big(\left(P(x)+2x\right)^2 + x^2\big) - a - 1\right) \, Q(x)\tag{3''}
\end{align}
$$

---

[ *EDIT* ] $\;$ Credit goes to [@The Phoenix](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1038520/the-phoenix) for noting in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4665890/291201) that if $x_0$ is a root of $Q(x)$ then so is $P(x_0)$ and $x_0 \ne P(x_0)$ by construction of $Q(x)$.

For a general polynomial $P(x)$ of degree $d$, its associated $Q(x)$ has degree $d(d-1)$. Any Tschirnhaus transformation $z=f\left(x, P(x)\right)$ defined by a symmetric polynomial $f(u,v)$ will send the pair of roots $\left\{x_0, P(x_0)\right\}$ of $Q(x)$ to the same root $z_0$ of the image, meaning each root of the image is a double root, so the result of the transformation is a perfect square $T^2(z)$. Therefore the problem reduces to solving the equation $T(z)=0$ of degree $\frac{d(d-1)}{2}$ i.e. half that of $Q(x)$.

The simplest symmetric polynomial in $\left\{x,P(x)\right\}$ is $P(x)+x$, which explains why the transformation $z=P(x)+x$ worked. It also means that the same transformation works for arbitrary polynomials to halve the degree of the resulting equation, and so do all symmetric transformations like $z=xP(x)$ or $z=P^2(x)+x^2\,$. For a cubic $P(x)$ this reduces the equation to solve from a sextic $Q(x)$ to a cubic $T(z)$, making it solvable by radicals.